# The certificate used to sign “APP” has either expired or has been revoked - ios10

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a new app, and just started to try and launch on an actual phone but continue to get the error below

```
The certificate used to sign "APP" has either expired or has been revoked. 
An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.
```

Here is what I have tried to fix it

1. Remove all certificates from developer account
2. Remove all certificates from KeychainAccess
3. Remove account from Xcode & close Xcode
4. Re-add account to Xcode
5. Check "Automatically manage signing" & have Xcode generate the signing

But I continue to get the error,

I have also tried manually generating a Certificate and manually Provisioning Profile, not using the "Automatically manage signing", and selecting the Profile 
which shows not build errors and when I click the info button says expires in 11 months and has all checkmarks

How can I fix this error?

Thank you very much for help in advance.

**EDIT**

I am now trying to do this manually, here are steps I take,

1. Revoke all certificates and delete all Prov. Profiles From Member Center and Local Machine
2. Create Certificate in member center with Keychain Access download and add the Cert to Keychain
3. Make Provisional Profile in Member Center, download Profile and import profile into Xcode
4. Run app, still get same error

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the date/time on the device you are trying to deploy the app on?

Comment: @Vin the date/time on the device I am deploying to is set automatically and is correct for my loation

Answer (score 4):

1. Sign in your account under Xcode->Preferences.
2. Select the team.
3. General->Signing , uncheck automatic signing
4. General->Signing(Debug), select the provisioning profile you have just created.
5. General->Signing(Release), select the provisioning profile you have just created.

Everything should work now..

Comment: 1.You didn't say that you are only in development. 2. I said "generally". 3.  The second sentence in your comment does t make sense, maybe rephrase? 4. What are you actually asking?! In your last paragraph you say that you have no build errors and then you continue saying how to fix the error! That makes no sense.

Comment: See edit please

Comment: I have replicated the issue at my end, did the above steps and fixed it. I have updated my answer.. Let me know how it goes..

Comment: I haven't created a release profile yet, can i leave that empty?

Comment: Create a release profile, or use the same one as debug for the time being..

Comment: In preferences under the account I have the Company with Role of Agent and then my anew with role of user which should i use

Comment: I only need one so i use the Agent, i don't know your setup.. Just use Agent..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123708/discussion-between-do2-and-iqueqiorio).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the following steps (you have made most of them as you have stated but try them in the following order):

1. **In the list with the view that you have attached, right click on each row and move each certificate to trash**
2. Go to member center download the right certificates again and click on them so
3. **Restart Xcode**
4. Go to build settings and set the right Code signing for debug/release - you should be able to see an option on the row that says "Identities from profile..."

If this doesn't work then you should consider revoking your certificate and then create a new one and the do the steps above again.

**Edit:**
First, move the apps source files to a new directory.

After that do the 1-4 steps from above.

Comment: Are you saying dont use the auto mange setting?

Comment: Yes @iqueqiorio, do it manually.

Comment: Under Code Signing Identity under the Target I only see [Dont code sign, iOS Developer, iOS Distribution]

Comment: See edit please

Comment: @iqueqiorio, check my update in my post. If it doesn't help you, do tell me and we´ll try to figure out why but this should work hopefully.